# Can Kivy Android app keep running after screen lock

Tags: android, python, kivy, android-camera

I am just beginning to learn Kivy and wish to build an app to run on Android that will keep running even after the screen locks. Specifically I want the camera to keep running and feeding data for analysis by OpenCV. Is it possible for a Kivy app to keep running after the screen has locked, and in particular to keep taking input from the camera?

I am worried that the android OS might consider that a security risk and prevent it, or that Kivy does not have that level of control over peripherals. I saw some posts somewhat related but they were about java programming and didnt specifically address the camera aspect anyway.

I dont know how to program in java, so Python & Kivy are my target solution right now.

Comment: Yes, it's possible https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Background-Service-using-P4A-android.service

Comment: Be aware, that it's not possible on iOS

Comment: As long as you keep notification in tray and call `startForeground` (keep Oreo in mind) you can execute any code, unless user press force-stop

Comment: @DimaRostopira Thanks, but I dont really understand much of that code. I gather it is somehow notifying the android OS your kivy app is a service and to display something at the top of screen to show it is running. How does that code reference my kivy app, so that android knows which app to treat as a service? I cant see reference to the kivy app name there.

Comment: It's too broad, I can't explain how android service works in comment or even answer. Oversimplified: your app isn't and can't be "a service", service is part of app, as long as it's running you app won't be killed. Foreground service - service with notification, has top priority and won't be killed, unless force-stopped by user.

Comment: OK thanks. I am trawling the web for examples that have comments to explain the code. The code at the link is a bit confusing. For example it declares service_name = 'S1' and package_name = 'com.something' which are then not used at all. I can see how these would be the package.name and package.domain values from a buildozer.spec file. But as they are never used I dont understand how the service relates to the Kivy app or APK.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kivi, I'm doing native development. Service must be declared in Android Manifest. Package name and service name must be the same as in manifest